# what is the Alternate for AddorUpdate method in EF Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, generics, entity-framework-core, repository-pattern

I want to achieve the ADDorUpdate() method in Generic repository using EF Core like below?
Can anyone help me?

```
  public virtual void AddOrUpdate(T entity)
    {
        #region Argument Validation

        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");
        }
        #endregion
         DbSet.AddOrUpdate(e => e.Id, entity);  
        this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Simply use

```
context.Update(entity);
```

It does exactly `AddOrUpdate` based on value of entity PrimaryKey (0 means Add, > 0 means Update):

```
public virtual void AddOrUpdate(T entity)
{
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");

     this.DbContext.Update(entity);  
     this.DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Hi Arman, I have found the same in Microsoft docs. But read an article in the internet as it's not gonna solve. Is it?

Comment: @Naurtosan Behavior of Update in EF Core 3 is what I said and it will work

Comment: Thanks, @Arman. I will check this. AndI have a small confusion, in my class, we have declared dbonctext and dbset . And in my constructor, we are setting like  
           this.DbContext = dbContext;
           this.DbSet = this.DbContext.Set<T>();                             So my question is can I set like Dbset.Update(entity);  instead of this.DbContext.Update(entity); . in my method. Can you please give reply ?

Comment: @Naurtosan Yes you can. Both of them do the same thing

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/disconnected-entities#saving-single-entities the primary key issue was not causing this to work for me.

Comment: does this actually work for anyone? I'm using EF 3,1, when trying to update a non existent entry I'm getting this exception " Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded."

Comment: What about when you aren't tracking entities though and you have a dup key conflict? An efficient raw SQL/MySQL query method is to "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" when a constraint is violated on a query and then update the instead. Otherwise you have dup queries to query a row to see if it exists then deciding to add or update it in your code, its less efficient and won't scale well where the other way does directly with the database engine you give it the data, it decides how to handle it with one query and less of a performance penalty. And in your code you may not know yet if its a dup...

Comment: NOTE: This only works for AUTOGENERATED keys, otherwise you will get ConcurrencyException

Comment: It throws error: The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

Comment: I just checked myself: if (ctx.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderId == order.OrderId)) ctx.Orders.Update(order); else ctx.Orders.Add(order);

Answer (score 4):

If you work with composite keys you can use next method I wrote:

```
public static void AddOrUpdateRange<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> set, IEnumerable<TEntity> entities)
            where TEntity : class
        {
            foreach (var entity in entities)
            {
                _ = !set.Any(e => e == entity) ? set.Add(entity) : set.Update(entity);
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will send request to DB for every entity. Also all calls to DB should be `async` (use `AnyAsync` in your case).

Comment: @МаксимКошевой the Add() or Update() will only change the local data. Only when calling SaveChange() will interact with database.

Comment: @Koen van der Linden I'm talking about `set.Any`. It will send a request to db for every entity.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the entity exists.
Like this:

```
book exists= context.Set<T>().Any(x=>x.Id==entity.Id);
```

Use like this.

```
if(exists)
context.Set<T>().Add(entity);
else
context.Set<T>().Update(entity);
```

Edit:
Since this is a generic method, you should create a constraint on the method for this to work. For example, an abstract class.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
public int Id {get; set; }
}
```

Your method should then have this constraint.

```
public virtual void AddOrUpdate(T entity)
 where T: BaseEntity{}
```

Your Entity should inherit from `BaseEntity`.

Comment: Hi Bolkey, getting an error as "Operator == cannot be applied to operends of type 'Tkey ' and T'key'"

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bolkay. Please find the link for IGenricRepo and GNericRepo https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/the-name-savechanges-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Answer (score -1):

EF Core (6 included) doesn't support AddOrUpdate functionality. One way to achieve it is to create *upsert* (insert or update) function in DB and call it with the help of EF method `ExecuteSqlRawAsync`.

Here is a sample table with upsert function using PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
 id int PRIMARY KEY,
 "name" TEXT,
 "position" TEXT, 
 unique_identification_number int8 unique
);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_employee(_id int, _name TEXT,_position 
TEXT,_unique_identification_number int8)
   RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE plpgsql
   AS 
$$
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO employee(id,name,"position",unique_identification_number)
   VALUES(_id,_name,_position,_unique_identification_number)
   ON CONFLICT(unique_identification_number)
   DO UPDATE SET 
       name = EXCLUDED.name,
       "position" = EXCLUDED."position"
   WHERE employee.id = _id;
END;
$$;
```

In the backend call the pg function using EF `ExecuteSqlRawAsync`:

```
var sql = @"SELECT upsert_employee(@p0,@p1,@p2,@p3)";
await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync(sql, 1,'test','hr', 12);
```

Such an approach is useful when your entity is detached, you don't work with auto-increment pk and you want to create only one transaction to DB (e.g. don't get the entity to check if it exists and then decide to create or update).

Drawback is that it's not generic.

Comment: This is a PostgreSQL answer, is not an answer to the question, should be a comment.