# How to create/update the database when starting an ASP NET MVC 6 application

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, app-startup

I have the application developed in ASPNET MVC 6, I used the entity framework, I already have the migration created which is already prepared to introduce values ​​in the database.

What I intend is that when starting the application it does the update-database, is it possible? If yes how to do.

That is, I don't want to do the update-database before starting the application.

Answer (score 1):

For .Net6, to run migrations on app start, you can add  code in the `program.cs`

```
using (var scope = app.Services.CreateScope())
{
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    var context = services.GetRequiredService<MyDBContext>();    
    context.Database.Migrate();
}
.
.
.
app.Run()
```

If it's more on seeding the data, you can refer this thread
[How to seed data in .NET Core 6 with Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581816/how-to-seed-data-in-net-core-6-with-entity-framework)