# Need help to understand the role of virtual ICollection in Entity Framwork of .Net

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Need a little help to understand the role of virtual ICollection in model of Entity Framework

```
public virtual ICollection<Staff> Staffs { get; set; }
```

Comment: It is only needed if you have [Lazy Loading proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/lazy).

Comment: What, specifically don't you understand about this? For example do you understand the purpose of the virtual keyword (in other words, have you read this page? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/virtual), and are just asking specifically about ICollection being virtual? Vice versa? Or are you asking for someone to explain both what an ICollection is and what the virtual keyword does?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70581816/how-to-seed-data-in-net-core-6-with-entity-framework   https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2014/05/part-6-how-to-seed-database-with-test.html   https://code-maze.com/migrations-and-seed-data-efcore/