# ConcurrencyException: Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-5.0, ef-core-5.0

I wanted to achieve the `AddorUpdate()` using EF Core.

I was trying to add or update while seeding the datbase.

```
var artist = await GetArtist();

_applicationDbContext.Artists.UpdateRange(artist);
await _applicationDbContext.SaveChangesAsync(default(CancellationToken));
```

`GetArtist`

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Artist>> GetArtist()
{
    var artistPath = Path.Combine(_env.ContentRootPath, @"wwwroot/Db/artist.json");

    return await ReadAsync<IEnumerable<Artist>>(artistPath);
}
```

**Entity**:

```
public class Artist
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**ReadAsync**

```
private async Task<T> ReadAsync<T>(string filePath)
{
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase,
        WriteIndented = true
    };

    using FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(filePath);

    return await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(stream, options);
}
```

But got an error as:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 'Database
> operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s).

It seems `This only works for AUTOGENERATED keys`  [also mentioned in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62449352/12012109),

Isn't there a way to `AddOrUpdate` without an if-else condition when I have GUID as a primary key?.

Json file:

```
[
  {
    "id": "f6222771-52dc-42dc-8d7f-922b74830171",
    "name": "ABC"
  }
]
```

Comment: Your code should work. `Update` sets state based on default values of primary keys, auto generated or not. Default value means `Added`, else  `Modified`.

Comment: I am always getting that error.

Comment: I don't, with the code you show. What happens in `GetArtist()`?

Comment: Can you post part of your json files?

Comment: i have updated with the json

Comment: Is there any duplications based on Id?

Comment: OK, so in the end, you just `Update` an entity with a non-default Id value. Looks like the Id isn't present in the database.

Comment: yes at first it won't be there because i have used this code to seed the database, that could be the reason?

Comment: Yeah, in that case the first insert should be forced.

Comment: so it seems this won't be usefull while seeding...

Comment: I think for seeding may use ``HasData`` do the InsertOrUpdate.