# EF Core update an existing entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I'm using EF Core and .NET 6 and I would like to essentially upsert an entity to a table - a fairly simple ask.

I have the following code:

```cs
var countries = GetCountries();

using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

    foreach (var c in countries)
    {
        // check if the country already exists.
        var exists = dbContext.Countries.Where(d => d.Id == c.Id).FirstOrDefault();

        // if already exists - update (rather than add).
        if (exists != null) 
        {
            exists.Name = c.Name;
            exists.DisplayName = c.DisplayName;
            ... // omitted other prop updates.

            dbContext.Countries.Update(exists);
        } 
        else
        {
            dbContext.Countries.Add(c);
        }
    }

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I was wondering - is there was a more efficient way to update without manually looking up then updating (it's not very performant).

Preferably, I was hoping there was a `Merge` method in EF Core but can't find anything useful (that's free...).  Rather than doing the manual lookup and update in this way.

I'm probably missing something very obvious here - thanks for any pointers in advance!

Comment: EF6 had [`IDbSetExtensions.AddOrUpdate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.migrations.idbsetextensions.addorupdate?view=entity-framework-5.0.0) which, according to [what is the Alternate for AddorUpdate method in EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62449078/what-is-the-alternate-for-addorupdate-method-in-ef-core), is replaced by `context.Update(entity);`. In your case, `dbContext.Countries.Update(c);`. (There are notes on the linked question about autogenerated keys and concurrency; this may not fit your situation).

Answer (score 5):

EF Core do not have `Merge`, or similar for Upsert.
You can improve performance of your query by selecting existng items in one batch. Also you do not need to call `Update`, just change properties.

```cs
var countries = GetCountries();

using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
    var dbContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

    var countyIds = countries.Select(c => c.Id);
    var existing = (await dbContext.Countries.Where(d => countyIds.Contains(d.Id))
        .ToListAsync())
        .ToDictionary(c => c.Id);

    foreach (var c in countries)
    {
        // check if the country already exists.

        if (existing.TryGetValue(c.Id, out var toUpdate))
        {
            // if already exists - update (rather than add).
            toUpdate.Name = c.Name;
            toUpdate.DisplayName = c.DisplayName;
            ... // omitted other prop updates.
        } 
        else
        {
            dbContext.Countries.Add(c);
        }
    }

    await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: Agreed.  Go get "all of the possible already existing" with a SINGLE call (where the answer has "contains").  and delay the .SaveChangesAsync to the end.

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by user19087368](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72352431) seems the most straight forward. I tested it on .NET 6 and it worked perfectly - adapted a little bit to my usecase:

Here is my version of it with the "guid" as the primary key:

```
public async Task CreateOrUpdateApplication(Application application)
{
    var itemExists = _dbContext
        .Application
        .Any(i => i.ApplicationGuid == application.ApplicationGuid);
    _dbContext.Entry(application).State = itemExists ? 
        EntityState.Modified : EntityState.Added;
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
public void InsertOrUpdate(Entity entity) 
{ 
    using (var context = new dbContext.Countries()) 
    { 
        context.Entry(entity).State = entity.Id == 0 ? 
                                   EntityState.Added : 
                                   EntityState.Modified; 

        context.SaveChanges(); 
    } 
}
```